# unexpected not all control paths return a value?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am currently writing a program in C++ and have created a function called parseText. When i run this function i get the warning "Not all control paths return a value" however after looking at this code multiple times i cannot find out why this is happening. Is this an incorrect error or have i missed something.

```
int parseText(std::string line, std::string *posResponses) {
    for (int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++) {
        line.at(x) = toupper(line.at(x));
    }
    if (line == "HELP") {
        runHelp(3);
        return 0;           //returns 0 if user entered invalid response and needs to repeat the code
    }else if (line == "QUIT") {
        return 2;           //returns 2 if user wants to quit 
    }
    if (posResponses->size() == 1 && posResponses[0] == line) {
        return 1;           //returns 1 if there was a valid response               
    }else if (posResponses[0] == "int") {
        int x = posResponses[1].size();
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            if (posResponses[1].at(i) < 48 || posResponses[1].at(i) > 57) {
                return 0;   //returns 0 if user entered invalid response and needs to repeat the code
            }
            return 1;       //returns 1 if there was a valid response
        }
    }
    else{
        int x = posResponses->size();
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            if (posResponses[i] == line) {
                return 1;   //returns 1 if there was a valid response
            }
        }
        return 0;           //returns 0 if user entered invalid response and needs to repeat the code
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is opinion-based, but this is where the "brace on the same line" format style is a detriment.

Comment: You probably just need to take that `return 1` out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this `if` branch

```
} else if (posResponses[0] == "int") {
    int x = posResponses[1].size();
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        if (posResponses[1].at(i) < 48 || posResponses[1].at(i) > 57) {
            return 0;   //returns 0 if user entered invalid response and needs to repeat the code
        }
        return 1;       //returns 1 if there was a valid response
    }
}
```

If `x` is assigned a value `< 0`, then the `for` loop won't be enterted at all, then no `return` statement for this branch.

Maybe you're sure that `x` won't be minus at run-time, but compiler has to confirm that for all the branches at compile-time.

I'm not sure about your intent, you might want

```
} else if (posResponses[0] == "int") {
    if (posResponses[1].size() == 0 || posResponses[1].at(0) < 48 || posResponses[1].at(0) > 57) {
        return 0;   //returns 0 if user entered invalid response and needs to repeat the code
    }
    return 1;       //returns 1 if there was a valid response
}
```

Comment: `std::string::size()` returns an *unsigned* type, usually `size_t`.  If it happens to contain a value greater than the max value of an `int` then an overflow occurs, which can cause `x` to be set to a value < 0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Or "purple", given that it's Undefined Behavior. Basically, for control flow warnings like this, possible run-time UB tends to make these warnings less reliable.

Comment: thanks I just put a return 0 outside of the for loop because for my intents you will never need to enter a value larger then the max value of an int.